# Paypal don't automatic redirect after transition

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal Sandbox account. I want to automatic page redirect my own website after payment successful order authorized.

Your transaction ID for this payment is: 8E7045675M462235P.
We'll send a confirmation email to ramesh@cognizsoft.com.

return to aman@cognizsoft.com
Go to PayPal account overview
Add funds from your bank

it's go to back on store when click on return to aman@cognizsoft.com

Comment: Are you working with Payments Standard or Adaptive Payments?

Answer (score 1):

With Payments Standard there is no guarantee the user will make it back to your site.  You can help things by enabling Auto-Return in your PayPal account profile, but even then the user could close the browser before the redirect happens and they would never make it there.

If you need to automate post-payment-processing tasks you can do that using [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) which will be triggered regardless of whether or not the user makes it back to your site.

If you would rather ensure that you will indeed end up on your site to finalize every checkout then you could switch to the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/).